Не создавая, не инценировая клик. Открыть окно для выбора файла
(x.i = eCr('input', {type:'file', accept:x.dts.upload+'/*'})).click();
x.i.onchange = e => {

В данный момент, создаю элемент, инсценирую клик.
После чего открывается окно для выбора файла.
Вопрос в том, придумали что то, когда не придется ни создавать файл, ни кликать по нему. Просто открыть окно из js для выбора файла?

Есть File System Access API...

Связанный вопрос


Вопрос в том, придумали что то, когда не придется ни создавать файл, ни кликать по нему. Просто открыть окно из js для выбора файла?

Есть File System Access API... Это пример как прочитать текстовый файл. Можно так же записать данные в файл.
Более подробнее в статье https://habr.com/ru/companies/timeweb/articles/653703/
  const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker()
  const file = await fileHandle.getFile()
  const fileContent = await file.text()
  console.log(fileContent)

